# Confusion about the definition maximal linearly ordered subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am reading Connell's Elements of Abstract and Linear Algebra (2002), specifically on Hausdorff Maximality Principle. At the end of the section, there is a practice exercise:

**Exercise:** Define a relation on *A* = $\textbf{R}^2$ by (*a, b*) $\sim$ (*c, d*) provided *a* $\leq$ c and *b* $\leq$ *d*. Show this is a partial ordering which is linear on *S* = {(*a, a*): *a* < 0}. Find at least two maximal linearly ordered subsets of $\textbf{R}^2$ which contain *S*.

The main trouble I am having with this exercise is the definition of "maximal linearly ordered subsets". The text does introduce the concept of partial and linear ordering, but not this. Some Google Search associates this concept with Zorn's Lemma, which I am not very familiar with. I hope someone can answer my question, and find those two subsets if possible.

Another thing is that because I'm self-taught, I am not very confident that my proof is correct. I will post it down below, so someone can check and correct me if I make any mistakes.

**Proof:** To prove that this relation is partial ordering, we must show that it is reflexive, anti-symmetric and transitive.

- Reflexive: If *a, b* $\in$ *A*, then we have *a* $\leq$ *a* and *b* $\leq$ *b*. As such, (*a, b*) $\sim$ (*a, b*).
- Anti-symmetric: If (*a, b*) $\sim$ (*c, d*) and (*c, d*) $\sim$ (*a, b*), then we have *a* $\leq$ *c* and *c* $\leq$ *a*. This means *a* = *c*. By a similar argument, *b* = *d*. As such, (*a, b*) = (*c, d*).
- Transitive: If (*a, b*) $\sim$ (*c, d*) and (*c, d*) $\sim$ (*e, f*), then we have *a* $\leq$
  *c* $\leq$ *e*. Similarly, *b* $\leq$ *d* $\leq$ *f*. As such, (*a, b*) $\sim$ (*e, f*).

To prove that this relation is a linear ordering on *S*, we must show this is a partial ordering with the additional property that if (*x, x*) and (*y, y*) $\in$ *S*, then (*x, x*) $\leq$ (*y, y*) or vice versa.

By a similar argument to the above's, we can see that this relation is partial ordering. We now show that this relation on *S* satisfies the additional property.

Let (*x, x*), (*y, y*) with *x, y* $<$ 0 $\in$ *S*. Since *x, y* $\in$ **R**, we have either *x* $\leq$ *y* or *y* $\leq$ *x*. As such, (*x, x*) $\leq$ (*y, y*) or vice versa. Thus this relation is linear on *S*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof that $\sim$ is a partial order is correct, it indeed follows quite easily from $\le$ on $\Bbb R$ being a linear order (which also implies, as you saw, the statement on $S$).

A maximal linearly ordered subset containing $S$ is just a subset $T$ of $\Bbb R^2$ that obeys:

1. $T$ is linearly ordered by $\sim$.
2. $S \subseteq T$.
3. If $T'$ is another subset satisfying $1$ and $2$ and also $T \subseteq T'$ then $T=T'$.

In words, we cannot add more points to $T$ without "spoiling" the linear orderedness. I'll leave you to puzzle on some potential $T$'s extending $S$..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It really helps my understanding.

Comment: After thinking for a while, would you mind giving some examples of maximal linearly ordered subsets? Your definition seems to imply that there exists only one such subsets, and the exercise I'm working on asking for two examples.

Comment: @Rampage I think $\{(a,a)\mid a\in \Bbb R\}$ would work as a $T$ that’s maximal.